# terraform setting hostname on multiple aws instances

Tags: terraform

I'm wanting to understand how user data can be used to set hostnames for 2 or more ec2 instances that terrafrom creates. Below is my  instance.tf which creates 2 instances.

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  count = 2
  ami           = "${lookup(var.AMIS, var.aws_region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {Name = "rb-${count.index}"}

  # the VPC subnet
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.dee-main-public-1.id}"

  # the security group
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.allow-ssh.id}"]

  # the public SSH key
  key_name = "${aws_key_pair.mykeypair.key_name}"
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "mykeypair" {
  key_name = "mykeypair"
  public_key = "${file("${var.PATH_TO_PUBLIC_KEY}")}"
}
```

How do I set the hostnames for those 2 instances. i.e web1.example.com, web2.example.com

I understand cloudinit or remote-exec can be used for this but struggling to come up with the code as I'm still a beginner. Really appreciate If I can get some help to come up to speed. Many thanks in advance.

-B

Comment: You need do that with `user data`, a quick reference for you: https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/9j6jgq/set_ec2_hostname/

Comment: Sounds like you want to set DNS and not the hostnames. I'd enable DNS on your VPC and create a route53 record to add those 2 names to each instance with a count and an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with data resource for template file which allows you to use count function. The below syntax will allow you use the hostname variable with the count function.

```
data "template_file" "init" {
  count = 2
  template = file("$path")
  vars = {
    hostname      = "web${count.index}.example.com"
  }
}
resource "aws_instance" "master" {
  ami           = "$ami"
  count         = 2
  instance_type = t2.medium
  user_data     = data.template_file.init[count.index].rendered
}
```